# Questions about C Programming Language (K&R) - Exercise 1-13

Tags: c, arrays

I am a newbie to programming.

I have 6 questions in the solution code for exercise 1-13 of C Programming Language (K&R). The task was to write a program that prints a histogram of the lengths of the words. As demonstrated in the picture.

I have pasted the code below along with the notes I made to help me understand.

My questions are next to the respective part of the code that I have questions about. Thanks in advance!

> ```
> int main ()
> {
>
> int c, i, nc, state;
> int len;                      /* length of each bar           */
> int maxvalue;                 /* maximum value for wl[]       */
> int ovflow;                   /* number of overflow words     */
> int wl[MAXWORD];              /* word length counters. Defining an int array with 11 character variables. This is the same as saying int wl[11]           */
>
>
> state = OUT;
> nc = 0;                       /* number of chars in a word    */
> ovflow = 0;                   /* number of words              */
> ```

1. What is the purpose of this for loop below? Does it initialize the array?

> ```
>     for (i = 0; i < MAXWORD; ++i)
>       wl[i] = 0;
>
>
> while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) //get a character
> {
>   if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') // if c is a blank, new line or tab
>   {
>       state = OUT;  // we are outside a word.
> ```

2. Below, we have `(nc > 0)` While nc is declared above, how is `nc` changed? as in how does the user change it? Where is the input for `nc`?

> ```
>       if (nc > 0) 
>
>           if (nc < MAXWORD) //if the number of characters is less than the maxword length counter.
>           {
>               ++wl[nc]; // increase the number of elements/number of characters in the array by 1.  
>           }
> ```

3. What does the increment operator in `++wl[nc]` increase by 1? Does it increase the array `wl`? What is the significance of `nc` in `++wl[nc]`?

   > ```
   >           else
   >           {
   >               ++ovflow; // if nc is greater than the maxword however, increase the overflow by 1
   >           } 
   >
   >       nc = 0;
   >   }
   > ```
4. Above, does `nc = 0` reset the number of characters?

> ```
>   // The beginning of a new word
>
>   else if (state == OUT) {  //if state is out or better put, if we are not in a word
>       state = IN;             // In that case, upon accepting a new character, we are at the start of a new word hence state is in.
>       nc = 1;                 // and upon accepting a character, the number of characters is 1.
>   }
>
>   // inside a word
>   else 
>   {
>       ++nc;                   // if not outside a word or in a word, increase the number of characters by 1
>
>   }
>
> }
> ```

5. In the line below are we initializing `maxvalue`?

   > ```
   > maxvalue = 0 ;
   > for (i = 1; i < MAXWORD; ++i) //Run a for loop until i is 10. Since MAXWORD length counter is 11.
   >   {
   >       if (wl[i] > maxvalue) //if the elements in the array is greater than the max number of elements allowed in the array
   >               maxvalue = wl[i]; //the max amount of elements allowed in the array is the same as the number of elements in the array. 
   >       }
   > ```
6. I don't get this part of the code. Could someone please explain it to me?

> ```
> for (i = 1; i < MAXWORD; ++i)
> {
>   printf("%5d - %5d : ", i, wl[i]); //i refers to the word length while wl[i] is the frequency of its occurence.
>   if (wl[i] > 0) {
>       if ((len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <= 0)
>           len = 1;
>
>   }
>
>   else
>       len = 0;
>   while (len > 0) 
>   {
>       putchar ('*');
>       --len;
>
>   }
>   putchar('\n');
>
> }
> if (ovflow > 0)
>   printf("There are %d words >= %d\n", ovflow, MAXWORD);
> ```

Comment: Fyi, single-stepping through these programs in a debugger, with a watch window open on local variables, would be *highly* educational in addressing pretty much all of this.

Comment: What WhozCraig said.  Note that you have 6 distinct questions here, which doesn't make it a good fit for the Stack Overflow format.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into what you have both suggested.

Comment: @WhozCraig Is there a debugger you would suggest?

Comment: `gdb` from a console, or a multitude of windowing wrappers that drive commands to gdb if you're into guis. Personally, I'd hit the web for a quick-info tutorial on gdb and old-school it from a console as a learning experience. Trust me, the effort it will pay for itself many time over. Don't forget to build with debug-symbols enabled (-g)

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks a mil! I learned something new!

Comment: @WhozCraig I just want to say a BIG thank you to you. I learned something of immense value. I wish others who had been quick to down vote the question had provided the sort of assistance you did. So thank you and please continue to assist others even though they might ask 'broad' questions. I will be using gdb henceforth thanks to you.

Comment: @Salamit Glad to help. You will find it astounding how much more you learn about working programs, and about broken ones, as you hone your debugging skills. I'm utterly shocked how, after years and years, solid interactive debugging skills are still not near the forefront of academic programs designed to teach software engineering skills. Imho, it should be a continually revisited topic for the first 2-3 semesters of beginning course work. Anyway, again, glad to help. Best of luck out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. yes
2. changed in `else if (state == OUT)`
3. the `nc'th` element in the `wl`  array is incremented (array[1] is the second element in array, so the nc'th element is actually the nc + 1...)
4. yes
5. yes
6. the for loop prints the word counter (which word is it) and its length.

if length of specific word is greater than 0  len gets the value `wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue` and then is checked against 0. if it equlas 0 then len becomes 1.

else: len becomes 1

after all this the program prints `len` times '*' and then a newline